# How to ensure that request has completed before testing headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I am trying to test that when a user clicks a link, a PDF file is downloaded.

```
it 'downloads a PDF', :js do
  find("a.btn", text: %r{Download}i).trigger 'click'
  expect( page.response_headers['Content-Type'] ).to eq "application/pdf"
end
```

This is failing with

```
expected: "application/pdf"
got: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

If I add `sleep 20` before the expectation, the test passes.

Is there a better/ more efficient way to write this?

For some reason, the following passes intermittently (even with longer wait durations):

```
expect( page.response_headers['Content-Type'] ).to have_text("application/pdf", wait: 20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`have_text` is a matcher that uses a page element (Capybara::Node::Element).  When you use it with a string the string gets parsed into an HTML document and then text nodes from that document are compared, but won't have any retrying behavior because it doesn't know how to reload the string (page elements store the query used to find them in the object so they can be reloaded - strings do not).  In order to get a waiting behavior on the string from the response_headers you'd need to use something a matcher that takes a block and retries.  https://github.com/abotalov/waiting_rspec_matchers is one gem that provides that sort of functionality, but there are a few others too.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for introducing me to waiting_rspec_matchers. Very useful and solves the issue! Curious why you decided to remove the custom method however? This seemed like it had potential and avoids adding another gem. Is it not a valid approach?

Comment: @AndyHarvey It's a valid approach, but I realized I was only explaining the query part, would still need the matcher part which has a bunch more methods needed and was going to be too long/complicated for a simple answer -  If you're interested in that approach, you should look at the TitleQuery and HaveTitle classes in Capybara as a good starting point.